# Passing function to arguments ifort vs gfortran

Tags: fortran

I'm experiencing a problem since I'm trying to run my fortran code with ifort, which was previously compiled with gfortran. One of my code's functions is using an other function as an argument, as shown below. Compiling the code with gfortran/ifort do not generate any errors.

```
module mod_rk4_2

implicit none 

contains 


!rk4 temporal scheme 
function rk4(f,dt,func) result(f_new)

double precision, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: f
double precision, intent(in) :: dt 
double precision, dimension(size(f,1),size(f,2)) :: f_new
double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable ::  k1, k2, k3, k4

interface 
    function func(f) result(res)
        double precision, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: f
        double precision, dimension(size(f,1),size(f,2)) ::  res
    end function func
end interface 


allocate(k1(size(f,1),size(f,2)),k2(size(f,1),size(f,2)),k3(size(f,1),size(f,2)),k4(size(f,1),size(f,2)))

k1=func(f)
k2=func(f+dt*k1/2)
k3=func(f+dt*k2/2)
k4=func(f+dt*k3)


f_new=f+dt/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)

deallocate(k1,k2,k3,k4)


end function rk4

end module mod_rk4_2
```

Running the code compiled with gfortran is fine, but when compiled with ifort, the code crashes at the first call of the forementioned function, with a stack overflow error message. Any ideas ?

```
forrtl: severe (170): Program Exception - stack overflow
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
main               00007FF779CCAE38  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
main               00007FF779C564E0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
main               00007FF779CCAC02  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
main               00007FF779CCB04C  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       00007FF9D8EC1FE4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          00007FF9D99BEFC1  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Comment: Please show a complete example.  We can't look much at this without a main program too.  See [mcve].

Comment: Similar to this page? https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/672035 which suggests (in the first reply) to set property Fortran > Optimization > Heap Arrays to 0

Comment: You should try compiling with standard checks and traceback.

Comment: I posted the best guess I could think of, with no MCVE to test, but further searching turned up the same link @roygvib shared. So, based on the responses, I’ll delete my answer and post the other possibility as a comment: since your `function` is array-valued, if it is directly recursive, it must be compiled with the `recursive` keyword.

Comment: As the previous comments imply, ifort and gfortran defaults differ about use of heap vs. stack , and the use of the ifort heap_arrays option (with no size parameter) is generally recommended for such cases.  It may make a difference whether you use CONTIGUOUS, thus the need for an actual reproducer.

Comment: Indeed the problem came from the array allocation on the stack instead of the heap, putting heap arrays to 0 solved the problem now the code is running. Thank you all !

Comment: [@ValentinPigeon Could you put a very simple answer to this question by yourself? (e.g. by citing the Intel page). Then this question will have an answer and looks nice :)]